# A function that will remove and return a part of a linked list based on its priority

Tags: python, list, sorting

```
class Node:
    """A node for linked lists in a sll."""
    def __init__(self: 'Node',
                  priority: int) -> None:
        self._next = None
        self._priority = priority

    def get_next(self: 'Node') -> 'Node':
        return self._next

    def set_next(self: 'Node', next: 'Node') -> None:
        self._next = next

    def get_item(self: 'Node') -> object:
        return self._item

    def set_item(self: 'Node', item: object) -> None:
        self._item = item

    def get_priority(self: 'Node') -> int:
        return self._priority

    def set_priority(self: 'Node', priority: int) -> None:
        self._priority = priority

class SLL():
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
    def take_part_of_list(self,pri):
```

I want to see if I can create a function without the use of import that extracts (removes and returns) a part of a single linked list. For example, if the linked list was

```
dog = SLL()
dog = (10)->(8)->(7)->(6)->(5)
dog.take_part_of_list(7)
```

that would return

```
(7)->(6)->(5)
```

Comment: Why are you using getters and setters with no side effects? You could just use the attributes normally.

Comment: I just added those to show what kind of nodes my single linked list will have

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> class Node:
...     def __init__(self, data=None, next_node=None):
...         self.data = data
...         self.next = next_node
... 
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Node({}, {!r})'.format(self.data, self.next)
... 
...     def __str__(self):
...         return '{} -> {}'.format(self.data, self.next)
... 
>>> class LinkedList:
...     def __init__(self, head=None):
...         self.head = head
... 
...     def add(self, data):
...         if self.head is None:
...             self.head = Node(data)
...         else:
...             tail = self.head
...             while tail and tail.next:
...                 tail = tail.next
...             tail.next = Node(data)
... 
...     def take_part_of_list(self, priority):
...         node = prev = self.head
...         while node and node.data != priority:
...             prev = node
...             node = node.next
...         prev.next = None
...         return LinkedList(node)
... 
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'LinkedList({!r})'.format(self.head)
... 
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self.head)
... 
>>> dog = LinkedList()
... dog.add(10)
... dog.add(8)
... dog.add(7)
... dog.add(6)
... dog.add(5)
... 
>>> repr(dog)
'LinkedList(Node(10, Node(8, Node(7, Node(6, Node(5, None))))))'
>>> str(dog)
'10 -> 8 -> 7 -> 6 -> 5 -> None'

>>> part = dog.take_part_of_list(7)
>>> repr(part)
'LinkedList(Node(7, Node(6, Node(5, None))))'
>>> str(part)
'7 -> 6 -> 5 -> None'

>>> repr(dog)
'LinkedList(Node(10, Node(8, None)))'
>>> str(dog)
'10 -> 8 -> None'
```

Comment: can this function remove the nodes from the original single list?

Comment: @KMAN Do you mean after `dog.take_part_of_list(7)` that `dog` would equal `10 -> 8 -> None`? Or `dog` equal `7 -> 6 -> 5 -> None`? Or something else entirely?

Comment: yeah so dog.take_part_of_list would return a single linked list of the removed nodes from dog also if possible could it be done in my sortedlist class?

Comment: There isn't a problem text I'm just trying to do this to work on a larger problem. I just want to make a function that would both return and remove all items in a single linked list from the spot that the priority occurs in the original linked list.

Comment: dog starts as 10->8->7->6->5->None when i call dog.take_part_of_list(7) it returns 7->6->5->None. So this modifies dog and removes the 7->6->5->None so dog would only be 10->8->None